# Discord.py Remove all users from 1 specific role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I already searched a lot but couldn't find a solution on stack for this case.

I want to remove all users from a role with 1 command.

```
@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role)
        for m in ctx.guild.members:
            try:
                await member.remove_roles(*roles)
            except:
                print(f"Couldn't remove roles from {m}")
        await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** experimental roles.')
```

I get following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\epic guard\bot.py", line 37, in swipe
    roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role)
TypeError: 'Role' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your current code:

```
@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        roles = tuple(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=n) for n in role)
        for m in ctx.guild.members:
            try:
                await member.remove_roles(*roles)
            except:
                print(f"Couldn't remove roles from {m}")
        await ctx.send(f'Removed **all** experimental roles.')
```

to this:

```
import discord

@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        for user in ctx.guild.members:
                role_name = 'Member' # Or enter the name of the role you want to remove
                member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role_name)
                await user.remove_roles(member)
```

You should probably change `role_name` variable to the name of the role you would like to remove from all of the members from a server.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the traceback, `discord.Role` object is not iterable. The only iterable attribute `Discord.Role` has is `discord.Role.members` and I think this is what you are looking for. You can iterate through all role users, then you can remove the role from all of them.

Also, you can use `commands.has_permissions()` in order to check if a user has necessary permissions.

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in role.members:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

## References

- [`discord.Role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.members)
- [`commands.has_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions)

Comment: @corsax1993 You just leaked your discord bot token. You should change it.

Comment: @corsax1993 So you're saying that your current code is:

```
from discord.ext import commands 
from discord.utils import get 
import discord  

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', help_command=None)    

@client.command() 
async def swipeall(ctx, role: discord.Role):     
 if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:         
  for member in role.members:             
  await member.remove_roles(role) 
```
Do you have administrator permission in your server? If you do, are you getting any errors? The command is probably not working because you don't have admin perms.

Comment: Its my server and my add and remove command works perfectly

async def add(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await user.add_roles(role)


i wont get any error with @Nurqm's code..  but users are still on the role..

Comment: In your guild's role hierarchy, is your bot's role lower than the role you're trying to remove? If it is, just drag the bot's role above that role. It should work.

Comment: the bot role is the highest possible role, i already double checked it :-(

Comment: i really dont get it. i can add user to groups, i can remove them 1 by 1.. but the code for all at once wont work.. weird :-O

Comment: sooo i tried to get all users from my role in a list and print it.. its empty.. so it looks like it cannot access somehow my role.members ?

Comment: The code should work fine. Are you sure anyone has that role?

Comment: I checked it, removed everyone, now i added 2 people to this role. i run .swipe command - nothing changes. The bot is in the hierarchy the highest and is even admin with all rights. :-( I'm despair :-(

Comment: Are you sure add-remove role commands works properly?

Comment: 1000% - before answering i removed and added with the same bot.

Comment: Can you remove the line `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)` and try again?

Comment: already done it without this. 

`@client.command()
async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in role.members:
        await member.remove_roles(role)`

this is how it looks atm. and wont work -.-

Comment: This code works fine on my bot. I'm not sure what the problem is. Do you have an `on_command_error` event?

Comment: I just created a new plane server, added a new user and give him a role called "test". In hierarchy, he is below the bot role, the bot has administrator permission. I could add and remove roles with my .add / .remove commands but the .swipe command also does not work here. So its not an issue by my other server. It is about the code..

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: @corsax1993 Does the role you want to remove contain spaces? If yes, you should do `async def swipe(ctx, *, role: discord.Role):` instead of `async def swipe(ctx, role: discord.Role):`